# Can we send a bulk sms from Twilio to 5000 to 10000 numbers and group the message recipients to single message thread instead of individual threads?

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api, twiliosms

We are currently using Twilio Message Resource (https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource ) ‘**MessageResource.Create**’ to send SMS. It works well for single recipient. We would like to support Bulk SMS, where a user can send SMS to 5000 to 10000 Phone numbers.

Can we achieve this through Message Resource or are there any other services from Twilio?

Also, currently, with **MessageResource.Create** or **Notify** service, even if we send sms to multiple numbers, every message has a separate **MessageSid** due to which, bulk sms sent to each number creates a separate message thread.

Is there a common Id or some parameter using which we could identify all the numbers to which bulk sms was sent and group them together in a single message thread (like a group)?

Answer (score 1):

Sending messages from a single Twilio Phone Number works well for low volumes of texts, but there are [limitations imposed by carriers which limit the amount of segments you can send per second](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002943027-Understanding-Twilio-Rate-Limits-and-Message-Queues#h_01F026611PX5077RHR86SHGBYQ).

To increase the throughput you need to use multiple phone numbers to send messages from, but instead of building this solution yourself, you can use a Messaging Service.

First, [create a messaging service](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181308-Getting-started-with-Messaging-Services#h_01F906QTN69ACWK177WYFSCQS8), and then, [add multiple phone numbers to your service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services/tutorials/how-to-send-sms-messages-services-csharp) to increase the message throughput. The more phone numbers in your service, the more messages can be sent in parallel.

Your code doesn't need to change a lot, but instead of specifying a phone number, you need to specify the Messaging Service by its SID:

```cs
var message = MessageResource.Create(
    body: "Ahoy!",
    messagingServiceSid: "MG9752274e9e519418a7406176694466fa",
    to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+441632960675")
);
```

Here's some more guidance on [how to send messages at scale](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/best-practices-at-scale).

---

There's no way to group your messages together. You'll need to group them in your own data store and query them if you need that functionality.

Comment: Your [linked article](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/best-practices-at-scale) makes a key point: "Using multiple long code or Toll-Free numbers to increase your message throughput to the US or Canada is strongly discouraged as it will result in carrier filtering".

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. This must've changed due to regulations, or carrier limitations. It still applies to other countries.